# href doesn't show URL, but actually works

Tags: html

https://krazydad.com/mazes/sfiles/

If you refer to above website, it has lit of links which points to some PDF files.  When I open the below link in chrome/firefox and press "Ctrl+U" - In the source code - I don't find the direct URL , but rather just the name and it has hyperlink for actual file.  How is that possible?

Below is the snapshot of code which is displayed when I press "Ctrl+U"

```html
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/layout.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="KD_AnimalMazes_v1.pdf">KD_AnimalMazes_v1.pdf</a></td><td align="right">2010-09-21 00:17  </td><td align="right">897K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/layout.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="KD_AnimalMazes_v2.pdf">KD_AnimalMazes_v2.pdf</a></td><td align="right">2010-09-21 00:25  </td><td align="right">897K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

But when I download that web page and open it using text editor, I can see the link directly. Not sure what's happening. Any clue?

I'm basically try to get URLs in the entire page and use it for download.

```html
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="Index%20of%20_mazes_sfiles_files/layout.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="https://krazydad.com/mazes/sfiles/KD_AnimalMazes_v2.pdf">KD_AnimalMazes_v2.pdf</a></td><td align="right">2010-09-21 00:25  </td><td align="right">897K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="Index%20of%20_mazes_sfiles_files/layout.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="https://krazydad.com/mazes/sfiles/KD_AnimalMazes_v3.pdf">KD_AnimalMazes_v3.pdf</a></td><td align="right">2010-09-21 00:28  </td><td align="right">896K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

Comment: I don't get it.  the page and the links and the link page all seem normal.  I am not understanding the issue from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers interpret non-absolute URIs as being relative to the current page. When saving a web-page, the browser will convert all non-absolute URIs to absolute URIs so that the links work when the page's location changes.

- `<a href="KD_AnimalMazes_v1.pdf">` is on this page: `https://krazydad.com/mazes/sfiles/`
- `https://krazydad.com/mazes/sfiles/` is interpreted as being inside a "directory" named `/mazes/sfiles`.
- Therefore `<a href="KD_AnimalMazes_v1.pdf">` is the same as `https://krazydad.com/mazes/sfiles/KD_AnimalMazes_v1.pdf`.

This rule has been part of HTML going back to HTML 2.0 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. I am not sure whether it will work or not but I had tried my best. It just uses string slicing and string concatenation.

```
<script>
var address;
var webadd  = window.location;
var element = document.getElementById("Some_ID");
if (element.href.indexOf("http") != -1) {
    address = element.href;
}
else {
    if(webadd.slice(-1) == '/')
       webadd = webadd.slice(0, webadd.lastindexOf("/") - 1);

     while (element.href.indexOf("../") == 1) {
         element.href.replace(/..//, "");
         webadd = webdd.slice(0, webadd.lastindexOf("/") - 1);
     }
     address = webadd + element.href;
}

console.log("Address is: " + address)
</script>
```